# Defining and using functions into Gruntfile.js

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I'm using a function to configure an object that I need in merge-json module. It works, but I don't know if this is a good or bad practice.

```
function getLanguageObj( src ){

    var inputTxt = '',
        inputObj = '',     
        tmp;

    for(var i in src){
        tmp = '';
        inputTxt += '"' + src[i].language + '":{files:[{src:[';

        for(var j in apps){
            tmp += '"<%= ' + apps[j].app + '.app %>/{,*/}*-' + src[i].language + '.json"';
            if( j < (apps.length - 1) ){
              tmp += ',';
            }
        }
        inputTxt += tmp + '],dest:"<%= secure.dist %>/languages/locale-' + src[i].language + '.json"},{'
            + 'src:[' + tmp + '],dest:"<%= secure.app %>/languages/locale-' + src[i].language + '.json"}]}';

        if( i < (src.length - 1) ){
          inputTxt += ',';
        }
    }

    inputObj = eval("(" + '{' + inputTxt + '}' + ")") ;

    return inputObj;

}

langObj = getLanguageObj( languages );
```

In `grunt.initConfig` I used:

```
"merge-json": langObj
```

Comment: You JSON.parse, a JSON.stringif-ied object that is returned from a call to eval() - why do you need the JSON.stringify and JSON.parse instead of just setting `inputObj` directly to the `eval`-ed string?

Comment: Yes Adam, you are right. That was redundant.